# Are events A and B independent? If so, why?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A hand with 5 cards is dealt from a deck of 52 cards.

Let A be the event that the hand is a four of a kind (4 cards of one rank and a 5th card)

Let B be the event that at least one of the cards in the hand is a queen

Are A and B independent? If so, why?

Comment: what have you tried? You should see if $P(A|B) = P(A)$

Comment: I don't think they are independent. I know the probability of A and the probability of B. I don't know how to show they are dependent

Comment: Maybe $P(B\mid A) = P(B)$ is easier to check.  Having only two different ranks in the hand should make it less likely that one of those ranks is queen.

Comment: Okay. But how do I calculate P(B|A)?

Comment: To calculate $P(B\mid A)$ intuitively rather than by definition, see if you can argue why among all four-of-a-kind hands there are exactly as many of them where the quadruple is made up of Kings and the kicker (*the remaining card not a part of the four-of-a-kind*) is an Ace as there are four-of-a-kind hands where the quadruple is made up of Aces and the kicker is a King.  And indeed, just as many where the four-of-a-kind is of rank $i$ and the kicker is of rank $j$ as there are where the four-of-a-kind is of rank $k$ and the kicker is of rank $\ell$ for any ranks $i,j,k,\ell$.

Comment: Obviously I don't know how to do it, that's why I asked for help

Comment: As for performing the calculation of $P(B\mid A)$ via the intuitive route... consider $P(B^c\mid A)$.  The probability the quadruple was not of queens is $\frac{12}{13}$.  The probability the kicker was not of queens given the quadruple was not of queens is $\frac{11}{12}$.  Thus, the probability the four-of-a-hand contained a queen is $1-\frac{12}{13}\times\frac{11}{12}=\frac{2}{13}$ which one can check is not equal to $Pr(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event the hand is a four-of-a-kind.  Let $B$ be the event the hand contains at least one Queen.

Approach via direct counting principles.

The probability the hand is a four-of-a-kind:  Pick the rank of the quadruple.  Pick the remaining card.

$$Pr(A)=\dfrac{13\times 48}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

The probability the hand contains at least one Queen:  This is the opposite probability than the probability that the hand contains no Queens.  Choose the five non-queen cards.

$$Pr(B)=1-Pr(B^c) = 1 - \dfrac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

The probability the hand contains at least one Queen and is a four-of-a-kind:  Pick whether the queen was the four-of-a-kind or the kicker.  Pick the other rank appearing.  Pick the suit of the kicker.

$$Pr(A\cap B) = \dfrac{2\times 12\times 4}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

---

You can verify now that $Pr(A\cap B)\neq Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ thus showing they are dependent.